# How to add user with SFTP access to '/var/www/html/adir' folder on Amazon EC2?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, sftp, chroot

This question is very much related to this question. The answer there is useful, but unfortunately incomplete. [How to add user with SFTP/ FTP access to '/var/www/html/website_abc' folder on Amazon EC2 Centos?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392601/how-to-add-user-with-sftp-ftp-access-to-var-www-html-website-abc-folder-on-a)

I want to grant third party access to a part of my directory structure on my Amazon EC2 instance. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/) to add a group and a user, and followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny) to chroot this user. It is unclear to me how to continue after these two steps though. Below are the steps taken in more detail, and where I am stuck.

**Add group and user**

In terminal:

```
sudo groupadd sftp
sudo useradd -g sftp thirdparty
sudo usermod -G sftp thirdparty
sudo usermod -s /bin/false thirdparty
sudo chown root:root /var/www/html/exports/thirdparty
sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/html/exports/thirdparty
sudo passwd thirdparty (set password e.g. to abcd)
```

**Chroot this user**

Add these lines to `etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Restart OpenSSH:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

**Remote access**

From this point it is unclear what to do next. The tutorials mention to use FileZilla, but not exactly how. I try the following.

*Attempt 1*

```
Host: 12.34.56.789 (public IP from EC2 Management Console)
Username: thirdparty
Password: abcd
Port: 
--> Quickconnect

Status:         Connecting to 12.34.56.789:21...
Error:          Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

*Attempt 2*

```
Host: 12.34.56.789 (public IP from EC2 Management Console)
Username: thirdparty
Password: abcd
Port: 22
--> Quickconnect
```

FileZilla warns about unknown host key. I click OK to trust the host and carry on connecting. I did not (yet) add the key to the cache.

```
Status:         Connecting to 12.34.56.789...
Response:       fzSftp started, protocol_version=2
Command:        open "thirdparty@12.34.56.789" 22
Command:        Trust new Hostkey: Once
Error:          Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Can anyone pinpoint me what to do next? Is this SSH related, or AWS specific (VPC related)?

Comment: server logs should guide you about the reasons of the failures. Or searching around stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 has SSH password authentication disabled by default and this is exactly what message in your `Attempt 2` case says. You need either set up login with ssh key for your user (good) or update `/etc/sshd_config` to enable password authentication (bad).