# SFTP via port 22 or vsftp over port 20 / 21 - Best way to secure FTP access to a server

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I've read many articles and questions on SF about this, and still can't figure out if the way I'm doing it is (a) possible, and (b) secure.

The server is running on AWS EC2, and all access is via SSH keys. I also only open port 22 to my own IP, but it seems if I want to allow others to access via SFTP, I'll need to open port 22 to the world (or spend my days managing firewall rules for dynamic IP addresses). Is this really better than, say, vsftp on port 21?

Assuming for the moment SFTP on port 22 is best, this is what I've done:

- Created an 'ftp' user with a public / private key
- Set up `/home/ftp/.ssh/authorized_keys` and tested SSH access
- Added a `ChrootDirectory` entry in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` pointing to `/var/www/html`
- Adjusted the permissions from `/var/www` downwards so the chroot 'works'

Now, I'm stuck in a seeming catch 22, which is, I suspect (hope), just misconfiguration. Without the chroot block in sshd_config, I can connect either via Putty or an SFTP client, and all is well - apart from having access to the whole file system. With the chroot block in place, I was hitting the `Could not chdir to home directory /home/ftp` error during authentication, as now the `/home/ftp/.ssh` folder is unreachable and so the keys don't work. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/392601/how-to-add-user-with-sftp-ftp-access-to-var-www-html-website-abc-folder-on-a) old question / answer suggests putting a `.ssh` folder *inside the `/var/www/html/` folder*, but that seems very odd to me - is that really OK to do, given that it's accessible by the web server?

Is there a more 'correct' way to have a user connect via SSH key and then be restricted to only /var/www/html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Comment: Not sure what makes you think this is a file permissions issue? This is about configuring chroot with SSH key access...

Comment: Also I did eventually get a functioning setup by setting the chroot location to `%h`, and then mounting the `/var/www/html` inside `/home/ftp/`. Now I can connect with SFTP. But I do still also see the `.ssh` folder in `/home/ftp`, and of course I can't make that inaccessible, or the initial SSH connection fails. So for now I've made those files owned by root, and only `authorized_hosts` is readable by others. Seems a locked down as possible.

Comment: have a look at restricted shells like ``rssh``.

Comment: @allo My sshd config file block is like that in @zoredache's answer below - specifically `ForceCommand internal-sftp`. I think that obviates the need for rssh - or did I miss something?

Comment: I guess it does. On the other hand, rssh enables rsync and other nice tools as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your OpenSSH configuration you can put some configuration in match blocks.  This lets you set different configuration for different users/groups/networks.

So you could put all your sftp users into a group sftpd and then add a block like this.  This forced chroot and forced sftp would only apply to that group.  Your main account would then be able to use a shell as normal.

```
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

> .ssh folder inside the /var/www/html/ folder, but that seems very odd to me - is that really OK to do

It isn't the worst thing.  One would hope that those users aren't making outbound connections, so there will be no keypairs, and no known_hosts in that folder, leaving only the authorized_keys file.  Which only has public keys in it.  Public keys are public, sharing them shouldn't be particularly dangerous.  Though it wouldn't be a bad idea to set the chroot directory for the sftp accounts at least one directory from the web root so that the .ssh isn't served publicly and outside the web root.  If your chroot was to `/var/www` and you set your root for the web server at `/var/www/html` that would seem to satisfy your concern.

Comment: I only have a single ftp user, so I used `Match User ftp`, but basically it's the same as what I have. If I understood your last point correctly, I should Chroot to `/var/www`, and have the keys in `/var/www/.ssh`, and then the web root is `/var/www/html`, so the ssh keys aren't available to the webserver - is that right? Any yes, they're only connecting 'in', so I removed the private keys and just left `authorized_keys`.